# Share one Power BI app with multiple users with different view settings

Tags: powerbi

I am quite new to Power BI apps and my knowledge is limited so I came here to ask the experts.

I have multiple dashboards and reports. Some of these dashboards and reports share common audiences whereas others do not. **My question is**- Can I create a common app where I bundle all the reports together and can control which users are seeing what reports (in one common app), not everyone has to see all the reports, eg in one common Power BI app- user A sees 3 reports, User B sees 5 and users C sees 2?

On the other side, what potential benefits do I have if I create different power Bi apps for different users based on their reports accessibility, again 25+ apps?

Comment: Are the reports in the same workspace? As you can only have one app per workspace

Comment: Yes they reside in the same workspace, can the view still be controlled? I want to be able to control the view of different reports to the different users. eg if I have 5 reports in one app- user A sees only 3 reports and user B sees only 2 reports, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one app per workspace, so in this use case you cannot deploy an app to each of the set of users with a different set of reports. You can't select both in the workspace or app, a way of only letting people see one or a number of reports only. If they have access to the workspace they see them all.

There are a few options you can try, separate the reports into themed workspaces, but if you have common reports, you will have dataset duplication (if you are using import mode).
One common pattern is to deploy the dataset(s) to one workspace, then create reports based on that one in other workspaces linked to those datasets.

For people that just need to see one or t2wo, you can share the report/dashbaord with them, and it will show up in the 'Shared with me' section of the Power BI Service

Comment: Thanks Jon for the answer, for reports in one workspace I understand that we can only create one app. However, for those reports in one workspace, would it be possible for me to set the view level of different users in that app? I want to make sure for the reports in one workspace I show different reports to different users as they have different KPIs and other calculations.

Comment: No you can't set a view level, per users. It's all items in the app, for all the users